# Javascript Multiple conditions from two or more functions

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Forgive me if this is simple. I'm new to javascript.

I'm trying to make certain divs appear or hide based on the users answer to questions. I've created a function for each question that gets the results of that question based on their value. But I can't get the && additional condition to work. I need the div to appear ONLY if both conditions are true. It doesn't even seem to recognize anything from && and beyond. Q1 also sets some of the text in the div based on the answer. That seems to be working fine.

```
// Question 1
function analyzeQ1(answerQ1) {
    if (answerQ1 == "TMC" || answerQ1 == "CMH" || answerQ1 == "SLH" || answerQ1 == "KU" || answerQ1 == "UMKC") {
        document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = " • Contact Research Administration at "+ answerQ1; + hideStuff('Q1a') + showStuff('A1')
    } else if 
        (answerQ1 == "Other") {
         showStuff('Q1a')
}
```

}

```
//Question 3
function analyzeQ3(answerQ3) {
    if (answerQ3 == "no" &&  answerQ1 == "TMC") {
        showStuff('A3') + hideStuff('Q3a')
    } else if
        (answerQ3 == "yes") {
            showStuff('Q3a')
}
```

Comment: You have a stray semi colon on this line: document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML

Comment: BTW - you can re-write that as the much cleaner `if ["TMC",  "CMH", "SLH", "KU", "UMKC"].indexOf(answerQ1) !== -1`  For old versions of IE, you can use this shim: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher  it doesn't seem to like that. I just replace the if line with that right? Keeping the curly bracket on the end?

Comment: I forgot to wrap the conditional up in parens () .. `if (["TMC", "CMH", "SLH", "KU", "UMKC"].indexOf(answerQ1) !== -1)`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Sweet! That is much cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet you have a stray semicolon:

```
document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML = " • Contact Research Administration at "+ answerQ1;
hideStuff('Q1a');
showStuff('A1');
```

In the second code snippet you refer to answerQ1 but never pass it in to the function so you need:

```
//Question 3
function analyzeQ3(answerQ3, answerQ1) {
    if (answerQ3 === "no" &&  answerQ1 === "TMC") {
        showStuff('A3') + hideStuff('Q3a')
    } else if
        (answerQ3 === "yes") {
            showStuff('Q3a')
}
```

Note that I used === vs ==. == is evil and you should forget that it exists in Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: if I remove that semicolon, it doesn't read the hidestuff and showStuff info. I get "Contact Research Administration at TMCundefinedundefined".  I also tried calling answerQ1 as in the second snippet, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks for the tip on the '===', I'll be sure to use that from now on.

Comment: @user1987534 Ah I see what you were going for. You do need the semicolon, but you should have the function calls on separate lines since you don't want the result of those added in to your display text.

Comment: @jhollman ok thanks! I moved the other two function calls on separate lines and then I was able to remove the semicolon no problem. Apparently it works with or without them if they're on their own lines. Another useful tip. But I still can't seem to get answerQ3 to also check answerQ1. In fact, even including what I have kills the functions called when the answer is "no".

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use a browser such as Chrome and open dev tools (F12) then setup breakpoints to debug and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Unless I'm using it wrong (probable), debug isn't finding anything wrong with it. JSlint can't find anything either. Thanks for the tips, I'll keep trying stuff.